# Unable to use .xjb file inside wsdlc ant task

Tags: wsdlc

I have a requirement of customize the default conversion provided by JAXB. For the xs:date type we need to show only the date part(removing the time). I have created an .xjb file and used the xjc command to generate the required classes. This is working perfectly and I got the desired results. Since in our project we create the web service jars using ant I tried to include it inside the wsdlc ant task I get the error as:
dateFormatter.xjb is not a xsd config file.
<target name="generate-service-from-wsdl" depends="validate-weblogic, clean">
        <taskdef name="wsdlc" classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.WsdlcTask" />  
        <wsdlc srcWsdl="${sourceWsdl}/My_Gateway.wsdl" 
            verbose="on"
            destJwsDir="${targetDir}" 
            destImplDir="${targetDir}/impl" 
            packageName="${servicePackage}"
             >
            <xsdConfig dir="wsdls/xjb" includes="dateFormatter.xjb"/>
         </wsdlc>
</target>
I am using Weblogic 9.2 and tried the using Weblogic 10.3 jar using the binding tag instead of xsdConfig. But I get the same error. Please let me know where am I making the mistake and how to correct it.

Thanks,

Govind.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this too. Looking at the Weblogic web service documentation, I realized binding expects a xsdconfig file (for xml beans) and not a jaxb binding file.
From weblogic documentation:
"Use the  child element to specify one or more XMLBeans configuration files, which by convention end in .xsdconfig."